# How to jQuery ajax with input field name="array[]"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, arrays, serialization

I have several dynamically created hidden input fields. Most of which have a name formatted as `array[]`

**Question 1:**

How can I use jQuery `.ajax()` or `.post()` to get the values from every field named `array[]` and pass them so they'll be retrievable as `$_POST['array']` in my PHP page?

**Question 2:**

Hypothetically speaking. Let's say that I don't know the name of said field but only the name of the form. How can I still do the same thing as in Question 1?

I found `.serializeArray()` in the jQuery documentation, but I have no idea what I'm doing with that and I'm not even certain if that applies to my situation of not knowing the field names.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want to use [`.serialize()`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) on the form.  This will make a query string of all form elements (including 'name[]' ones).

```
$.post('/url/to/post', $('#form').serialize(), function(data){
   alert('POSTed');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use jQuery's `.serialize()` method.
[Check it out](http://jsfiddle.net/VbqSS/)